# C# Read text (output?) from console that runs as a Process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if username and password for git repository is valid. In console I run:

```
git clone http://username:password@server/test.git
```

And I get:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for ...
```

So now I know username and password are not valid. I'm trying to run this command as a process:

```
var process = new Process
{
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
          FileName = "git.exe",
          RedirectStandardInput = true,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          RedirectStandardError = true,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          WorkingDirectory = "some_directory"
          CreateNoWindow = true,
           Arguments = "git clone http://username:password@server/test.git"
      },
};
process.Start();
```

I'd like to access the result of this command. Both **process.StandardError** and **process.StandardOutput** are equals **string.Empty**. Is there any way to read the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should read the [exit code of the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_ExitCode).

```
process.ExitCode
```

If the process failed, the return value should be non `0`. Of course you can only retrieve the exit code after the process completes.

So:

```
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
    //error
```

Please note: I haven't tested it but it is standard convention.

To read the output, one normally uses:

```
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.WriteLine(err);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is your standard output, which can be accessed as below:

```
string stdout = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

and use `p.WaitForExit();` right after because sometimes it takes a while to give error message.